# State Space conversion of Sinusoidal model

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic, state-space

i would like to learn how to convert  sinusoidal model into state space form which has  following equation

[image]

our model consist of  sum of periodic components with additive of white noise, given by following form

$y(t) = A_1\sin(\omega_1 t) + A_2\sin(\omega_2 t+) + ... + A_p\sin(\omega_p t) + z(t)$ where  $z(t)$ is additive white noise and

$\omega_i=2*\pi*F_i $

i was reading special  document  [Tracking a Sine Wave](http://iaac.technion.ac.il/workshops/2010/KFhandouts/LectKF10.pdf)

i somehow understand step when we have  single sinusoidal components, but what about  when we have several ones? please help me

Comment: It seems you are confusing signals and systems. State space model applies to "systems", i..e things that have an input and output. Your sine+noise model is just a signal

Comment: so can't apply Kalman filter to this model?

Comment: hi: based on what you explained, you only have a measurement equation. There is no system equation. so, if you let $F$ be the $p \times 1$ vector of  where  each element is $A_i$ and you let $\theta$ be the $p \times 1$ vector where each element is $sin(w_i \times t)$, then $y_t = F^\prime  \theta_t + \epsilon_t$  and that's it. Nothing is being estimated so there are no updates, atleast based on the way you explained it.

Comment: P.S: I just read Hilmar's answer again and I'm probably saying the same thing as him so my bad for duplication.